# How to make window border brush dynamic

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-10

So if a user of windows 10 sets a bunch of pictures to be shown as Desktop Background "Slideshow", the accent color is being changed to fit each picture
now all windows opened on that desktop are gonna have the same accent color as border color, but when i use WPF to Design my program's interface, the window's border will have the solid color that i picked while designing.

So is it possible to set my border brush to be dynamic just like other windows?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you just want to set the window's border colour to the current accent brush?

Comment: well yes, i want to make my border brush dynamic so it updates itself to be equal to accent brush whenever the accent brush is changed, or at least how to get the accent brush!

Comment: but wait, dont we set the Value of Windowstyle attribute to None which hides it at all?
so the Windows accent color is being changed functionally, the actual function still tries to change the Mainwindow border brush which does not exist in our case! am i right? if so, is there anyway to make the new custum border take the place of that terminated border, so the function will change its brush instead?